# Website doesn't see newest session values until I refresh page, but refreshing resets values of controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

My ASP.NET website doesn't see newest `Session` values. When my form is being sent to the server after clicking the button, the result sent back to browser depends of `Session` values. I process them in `Page_Load` method. It doesn't see the last change od `Session` values, but one before last. It looks like button's event handlers are executed before page's event handles but I'm not sure if it is like that. 
I tried to do my code in other methods like Page_PreInit etc, but it's still the same like that. The only thing that works for me is refreshing the page: `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);` after any change of any `Session` value, but it resets values of all controls, which I want to be the same as before. Is there a better solution?

**Example:** when It runs first time, the label's text is "Click the button", but when I click any of the buttons one time, nothing happens. When I click any of the button second time, label's text is the value of first click (even if I click A and then B, value changes to A after clicking B).

form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="A" onclick="Button1_Click" />&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="B" onclick="Button2_Click" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Event handlers:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["Letter"].ToString();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Letter"] = "A";
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Letter"] = "B";
    }
```

Global method:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["Letter"] = "Click the button";
}
```

Comment: `show your code!!!`..also show where in code you are initializing / declaring the session variables.. also there is a difference between using Session{"yourvariable"] and HttpContext.Current.Session["yourvariable"] also sounds like you have some IsPostBack Issues or Page_Load resetting of session variables going on

Comment: My code is long, but I'll try to write some short example and then edit my question.

Comment: are you using the `Global.asax` particularly initializing in this method `protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your code its very difficult, but is sounds like you are setting a Session collection value in the code of a button's click event( or some other control/event ), and expecting it to be in the SESSION collection during the Page_Load event.

It doesn't work like that - When the page request comes in, Page_Load happens before the control's events.

Instead of Page_Load use Page_PreRender this event occurs before the page is prepared to be sent back to the client.

Your addition of the code confirms the above.

Normally I wouldn't use Session_Start to initialize stuff like this, use Page_Load and IsPostBack property

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack){
       Label1.Text = "Click the button";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought I tried all Page's event handlers, but I must have missed this one...

Comment: No, I didn't miss that. It works for my simple example, but doesn't work for my Website. Doesn't show result in browser. Let me think a while before I accept your answer.

Comment: For that to work you will need to recreate the Button in the page's  Init event...

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment because I wasn't sure if I was right. Yes, instruction like that: `Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);` doesn't work in `Page_PreRender`. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is correct and helpful, now I understand what was wrong. But how does it work when you want add item to basket in internet shop and there are items to buy and items put to basket on the same page? When you add item, you have to generate new page with items to buy and items put to basket with buttons to remove these items. So you have to first call button event and then generate the page with new buttons and add buttons' event handlers, but you can't add event handlers after you call event. It's a bit strange. Do you normally use `Request` property?

Comment: You would add them items to the order in the button event handler, then render the order ( ideally using data binding). You need to understand the page request cycle a bit better then all this will make sense...but the 'modern' web relies much more on client side scripting and background web requests, there may only be one page request when you the page is first loaded and everything else is AJAX.

Comment: See this section on MSDN describing and mapping out The ASP.NET page life cycle, there is also a link to the Application life cycle on this page too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx